# Heroku looking for the wrong wsgi file. Django

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm on Django, but I'm not sure if it matters. Anyway, I get an `Application Error`, and when I check the logs I see the error:

```
 ImportError: No module named redlibros.wsgi
```

And it is fine cause the wsgi file is not name "redlibros.wsgi", I don't even know where it gets that name. The module is named

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'letrasclub.wsgi.application' # on my settings

web: gunicorn letrasclub.wsgi --log-file -   # on my procfile
```

and on my folders it looks like this:

```
LetrasClub
    letrasclub
       wsgi.py
    templates
    static
    ...
```

Any idea where to find the error?

**EDIT**

Ok, some extra info: I have a different repo, with a different Heroku remote. I copied that repo, changed the app, created a new Heroku remote and then pushed to the new one.

So, if I write

```
git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/letrasclub2.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/letrasclub2.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/Alejoss/LetrasClub2.0.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Alejoss/LetrasClub2.0.git (push)
```

Looks fine, if I go to the old app location and write the same command I get the old remote, the one that is related to the "redlibros.wsgi" app, perfect.

Now, why when I try to push the new app to the new heroku remote, I get the error that means Heroku is looking for the Old wsgi file, I changed the wsgi name, I changed the Procfile, I changed the wsgi file declaration on the settings, what am I missing?

Comment: What does your Procfile look like?

Comment: Ok, the problem just solved itself, I'm not sure what I did to solve it. I'm not sure if I should close this question cause it won't help anyone.

Comment: Describe what You do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look at wrong project.

You look at https://github.com/Alejoss/redlibros (I guess it's Your project), not at https://github.com/Alejoss/LetrasClub2.0

Comment: Damm, the man check github repositories when we think about Procfile and project structure! what a pro! :D

Comment: Thanks for you answer, just added some extra information that might help.